# Merging a list with a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of lists:

```
[['John', 'Sergeant '], ['Jack', 'Commander '], ['Jill', 'Captain ']]
```

How can I merge it with a single list like:

```
['800','854','453']
```

So that the end result looks like:

```
[['John', 'Sergeant', '800'], ['Jack', 'Commander', '854'], ['Jill', 'Captain', '453']]
```

Initially I tried:
`zip(list_with_lists,list)` but data was obfuscated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
a = [['John', 'Sergeant '], ['Jack', 'Commander '], ['Jill', 'Captain ']]
b = ['800', '854', '453']
c = [x+[y] for x,y in zip(a,b)]
print c
```

Result:

```
[['John', 'Sergeant ', '800'], ['Jack', 'Commander ', '854'], ['Jill', 'Captain ', '453']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution with `enumerate` instead of `zip`:

```
a = [['John', 'Sergeant '], ['Jack', 'Commander '], ['Jill', 'Captain ']]
b = ['800','854','453']
c = [a[i]+[bi] for i,bi in enumerate(b)]
```

Using `zip` is definitely the more pythonic solution in this particular case. However, sometimes you want have access to indices (yes, even in Python), so it's useful to know about `enumerate` too.

Answer (score 1):

`range` instead of `zip`

```
a = [['John', 'Sergeant '], ['Jack', 'Commander '], ['Jill', 'Captain ']]
b = ['800','854','453']
c = [a[x]+[b[x]] for x in range(len(b))]
print c
```

or update original list:

```
[a[x].append(b[x]) for x in range(3)]
```